# How to save urdu tweets and save in csv file using python

Tags: python, twitter

I want to save the tweets text only in urdu right now everything is working fine and tweets are saving in the csv format i just need to clean the data while saving in csv file

**tweets text is saving in this format**

**@hinaparvezbutt خدا کے لئے پاکستان کےلئے اگر اور کچھ نہیں کر سکتے تو کم از کم اردو میں نقطہ نظر لکھ دیا کریں اپنی ق… t.co/GyOeDqydIG.com**

**i just need to save the text like this**

**خدا کے لئے پاکستان کےلئے اگر اور کچھ نہیں کر سکتے تو کم از کم اردو میں نقطہ نظر لکھ دیا کریں اپنی ق**

while i have used regular expression to clean the text but i am failed to save it inside the tweets array

this is my code

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
# set access token and secret
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
# create tweepy API object to fetch tweets
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
tweets = []
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="اردو"+" -filter:retweets",count=1000).items(1000):
    text=re.sub(r"[#.A-Za-z0-9@;:/\n]", "", tweet.text, flags=re.UNICODE)  
    tweets.append(tweet)
tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(vars(tweets[i]) for i in range(len(tweets)))
FILE_PATH = "mysample.csv"
tweets_df.to_csv(FILE_PATH)
tweet_atts = [
'text', 'created_at', 'favorite_count',
'lang', 'retweet_count', 'source',
'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'retweeted',
'id'
]
tweets_df = tweets_df[tweet_atts]
tweets_df.to_csv(FILE_PATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the dictionary of each tweet, there is the key 'lang'. Filter by lang = 'ur'.

```
# import and authentication
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

# API object allows to make calls to Twitter API
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Owner's timeline tweets
api.home_timeline()

tweets = []
# tweepy.Cursor allows to iterate through objects (for example, tweets)
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(1):
    if (status.lang = 'ur'):
        # print(status.text) 
        tweets.append(status)
```

Comment: while saving into the array i want to clean the text by applying the regular expression and then save it into the array